# Linux/C++ shared libaries: Can I edit the sybol table, i.e. which symbols are exported?

Tags: object, shared

My question refers to a closed-source .so, which I received from another company. Unfortunately this .so has Boost1.33 statically linked into it, and it exports the boost::... symbols, which my application wants to use. This leads to a SEG FAULT as soon as using boost::start_thread().

My idea was that if there are tools to read the symbol table, it might as well be possible to edit the symbol table (concerning visibility/export).

Is that postmortem editing in general possible? Is there even such a tool available? If not, how would I approach developing such a tool?

Comment: readelf -Ws lib64/libvlutil.so | grep boost | grep start | grep thread
                                     delivers:                                 
1638: 00000000001ee2a0   353 FUNC    GLOBAL DEFAULT   12 _ZN5boost6thread12start_threadEv
  5637: 00000000001ee2a0   353 FUNC    GLOBAL DEFAULT   12 _ZN5boost6thread12start_threadEv

  #################                    nm -gC lib64/libvlutil.so | grep boost | grep thread | grep start
                       delivers:                    
00000000001ee2a0 T boost::thread::start_thread()

Answer (score 1):

Run `info binutils` to get a list.

Note, I'm presuming that your trouble is that the closed-source lib (aka alienlib herein) has semi-defective copies of the boost routines, has only some of them (and not some of the ones you need), so you get conflicts of sorts.

And ... That you would like to neuter the alienlib copy of boost symbols, so you can link in your own copy of a boost .so???

You can sometimes rename symbols with a `linker script` which can either rename symbols or list the ones you want to keep public.  You "link" to the linker script file [a text file] and it refers to alienlib)

There is a BFD library (official name "big fucking deal") that can read/write *any* binary/library format and it's what objdump is based on.  And, they take the word *any* very seriously.

Note that symbol tables fall within a specific range of a .so file.  Get a hex dump program that also spits out ascii on the right side.  You'll be able to get the hex ranges.

Also, the `strings` program with `-t x -a` and it will show you the hex offsets of the symbols.

Note that if there were only a few, you could do this manually with a hex editor program.  Note there are some spiffy ones around, but the `xxd` program can produce a hex dump and it can "crush" a hex file back into binary, so that's a fallback on this.

Now that you have the range, you can write a C program that can mmap the alienlib file.  You can rip through the symbol table range, looking for all "boost" strings and just change "boost" into zoost or boots or zcrab or whatever you like that is the same number of chars.  Note that when I say string here I mean `char str[5] = { 'b', 'o', 'o', 's', 't' };` and *not* `char *str = "boost";`

Answer (score 1):

objcopy -w -L _ZN5boost* libvtutil.so 
made a change by localizing a lot of boost symbols. However, I am still fighting a(nother?) problem