# How to tell linker not to look for certain symbols in a linked shared library?

Tags: linux, gcc, cmake, linker

My situation is as follows: our program depends on a ton of shared (and static) libraries. I want to add a new dependency, which is a static library. The program compiles with no issues, but it crashes during runtime. As it turns out, the new static library defines a symbol `foo` which is available in one of the many shared libraries. So the linker links to the shared lib's `foo` instead of the new static library's `foo` -- then the wrong `foo` is called during runtime, causing the crash.

I created a minimal example to emulate this: https://gitlab.com/luizromario/linker_example

There, we have:

- A lib called `libstatic_old`, containing a single function `print_thing()` which prints `old static lib`
- A lib called `libstatic_new`, containing a single function `print_thing()` which prints `new static lib`
- A shared lib called `libdynamic` that links to `libstatic_old`. It contains a single function `do_things()` which:

  - Prints the following message: `about to print thing from dynamic lib (should print "old static lib"):`
  - Calls `print_thing()`
- An executable called `executable` that links to libdynamic and libstatic_new. It:

  - Prints: `about to do things from executable`
  - Calls `do_things()`
  - Prints: `about to print thing from executable (should print "new static lib"):`
  - Calls `print_thing()`

If I link `dynamic` first, then `static_new`, this is the output:

```
about to do things from executable
about to print thing from dynamic lib (should print "old static lib"): old static lib
about to print thing from executable (should print "new static lib"): old static lib
```

If I link `static_new` first, then `dynamic`, this is the output:

```
about to do things from executable
about to print thing from dynamic lib (should print "old static lib"): new static lib
about to print thing from executable (should print "new static lib"): new static lib
```

In both cases, I'm not able to manage telling the linker that, for the executable, it should look for `print_thing` in `static_new` and, for the shared lib, that it should look for `print_thing` in `static_old`. Even though we have the code for `static_new` baked into the executable (right?) and the code for `static_old` baked into the shared lib, the linker can only link, for the entire executable, to either one or the other.

Of course, I could simply not link to two different libraries that define the same symbol, but unfortunately, in the real scenario, the shared lib is a prebuilt binary which I cannot build again. So, when compiling `executable`, is there a way I can tell the linker not to look for `print_thing` in `libdynamic`? Or some way to remove the `print_thing` symbol from `libdynamic`?

---

EDIT: someone else described a similar issue here: [Linux/C++ shared libaries: Can I edit the sybol table, i.e. which symbols are exported?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33384815/linux-c-shared-libaries-can-i-edit-the-sybol-table-i-e-which-symbols-are-ex)

I might try that, but I'd really prefer not to edit the shared library.

---

EDIT 2: after some trial and error, I managed to edit one of the `print_thing`s in the `libdynamic.so` binary into `print_thong` and that did the trick:

```
about to do things from executable
about to print thing from dynamic lib (should print "old static lib"): old static lib
about to print thing from executable (should print "new static lib"): new static lib
```

That's really unreliable, though, and I can't simply find and replace all `print_thing`s in the binary because there's another `print_thing` in the binary which I can't edit (otherwise the execution fails):

```
about to do things from executable
./executable: symbol lookup error: /home/c/luizromario/local/linker_example/build/libdynamic.so: undefined symbol: print_thong
```

I'd still prefer to tell the linker not to look for `print_thing` inside of `libdynamic`

---

EDIT 3: I might be inching closer to a solution.

I found out about the `--exclude-libs` linker option and used it like so:

```
target_link_options(dynamic PRIVATE "-Wl,--exclude-libs,libstatic_old.a")
```

The end result is exactly what I want:

```
about to do things from executable
about to print thing from dynamic lib (should print "old static lib"): old static lib
about to print thing from executable (should print "new static lib"): new static lib
```

Unfortunately, I need a non-invasive solution since, as I mentioned, I can't rely on being able to recompile the dynamic lib

Comment: I recommend (if the involved libraries are open source) to change the conflicting name and rebuild most of them. Perhaps also open an issue on their github repository

Comment: That wouldn't work unfortunately, for several reasons, but mainly because there are dozens of these dynamic libraries, some opensource, some not. It wouldn't be practical to try and rebuild everything.

Comment: You could use dynamic library loading in your code to explicitly link to the shared lib code and then let the loader pick up the static libs defs.  However it seems those two libs are overlapping a concerning amount...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking into `ld`'s manual, I noticed the following option:

```
   --exclude-libs lib,lib,...
       Specifies a list of archive libraries from which symbols should not
       be automatically exported.  The library names may be delimited by
       commas or colons.  Specifying "--exclude-libs ALL" excludes symbols
       in all archive libraries from automatic export.
```

I managed to use it to do what I want. It's tricky, but it works reliably enough and *I didn't need to tamper with `libdynamic.so`*.

1. Add the `--exclude-libs` link option to the executable:

```
target_link_options(executable PRIVATE "-Wl,--exclude-libs,ALL")
```

2. Link to `static_new` first, then link to `dynamic`.

```
target_link_libraries(executable static_new dynamic)
```

Done!

```
about to do things from executable
about to print thing from dynamic lib (should print "old static lib"): old static lib
about to print thing from executable (should print "new static lib"): new static lib
```

Note: **The link order matters.** Linking `dynamic` first then `static_new` will make the execution fail:

```
about to do things from executable
about to print thing from dynamic lib (should print "old static lib"): old static lib
about to print thing from executable (should print "new static lib"): old static lib
```

---

**What's going on**

From what I understand, `--exclude-libs ALL` tells the linker to, for each linked library, exclude every symbol the linked library exports. So, in my example, what `ld` is doing is:

1. Link `executable` to `static_new`

   - The call to `print_thing` in `executable` will point to `static_new`'s `print_thing`
2. Exclude all symbols exported by `static_new` from the resulting `executable`

   - `print_thing` is no longer available in the `executable` binary
3. Link `executable` to `dynamic`

   - The call to `print_thing` will *certainly* point to `dynamic`'s `print_thing`, since we've excluded `static_new`'s `print_thing` in the previous step
4. Exclude all symbols exported by `dynamic`

**Why the order matters**

Linking `dynamic` first fails because `ld` will then do the following:

1. Link `executable` to `dynamic`

   - Since `dynamic` exports both `print_thing` (from `static_old`) and `do_thing`, both references to these symbols in `executable` will point to the code baked into `libdynamic.so`
2. Exclude all symbols exported by `dynamic` from the resulting `executable`

   - It doesn't matter, `print_thing` has already been linked
3. Link `executable` to `static_new`

   - Nothing happens, `print_thing` was already defined in step 1.
4. Exclude all symbols exported by `static_new`

---

Unfortunately, I still haven't managed to solve the problem in my original project because of issues with link ordering, but I'm closing this because the specific matter of linking has been solved.